# Embed *.pdb files in managed library with Visual Studio 2022 17.1

Tags: nuget-package, visual-studio-2022, pdb-files

The 17.1 update for Visual Studio 2022 recently hit and one of the added functionalities is:

> When building managed libraries developers can choose to embed their source files with the debug information (PDB file) that is produced by the build, and even embed the PDB file into the assembly itself. We now surface embedded source as part of Go to Definition if a referenced assembly has embedded source and the PDB is available. This allows you to navigate to the original source files that declare the target symbol. Place your cursor on a symbol and press F12 to navigate to the original source file.

However I can't find anything on how to do that.

Does anyone know?

In addition, if I want to publish a package to NuGet and make it so anyone who adds that package to their solution can debug my package's code, do I only need to embed the PDBs or is something more required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's an option found in project properties:
[image]